# Elasticsearch count terms Ignore cases

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, lucene, aggregation, nest

Following is my aggregation.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "cities": {
            "terms": {
               "field": "city.raw"
           }
    }
}
```

Mapping

```
"properties": {
    "state" : {
      "type": "string",
      "fields": {
        "raw" : {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
```

Works great. But it groups the fields considering the case sensitivity.

eg.

```
{
    "key": "New York",
    "doc_count": 45
},
{
    "key": "new york",
    "doc_count": 11
},
{
    "key": "NEW YORK",
    "doc_count": 44
}
```

I want the result to come like this

```
{
    "key": "new york",
    "doc_count": 100
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522863/elasticsearch-case-insensitive-query-string-query-with-wildcards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that u use the raw version of the indexed string

```
city.raw
```

You don't have any analyzed version of your filed ?
It should be great if you also put the mapping of the field in the example.

Update: U should use a custom analyzer for what you need. The tokenizer should be keyword and the filter lowercase. Then index your data with this analyzer. Then should work.

```
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "type":         "custom",                       
                    "tokenizer":    "keyword",
                    "filter":       "lowercase"
                }   
            }
```

And some info [KeyWord Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) and [Custom Analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-analyzers.html)

Comment: added the mapping to the question.

Comment: yea thanks. Another small query do i need to recreate the index to add the analyzer because if i try to update it i get an error message saying that the index is already existing.

Comment: so i recreated the entire index with the analyzer and added the mapping and then seeded the data. Would have been nice if I could just add the mapping and update it

Comment: yes. you must recreate the index if you want to add new analyzer.